# IP neigh on Ubuntu gives no response on VMWare

Tags: command-line, networking

I'm running Ubuntu on VMWare Workstation Pro. And I'm trying to run the command `ip neigh` on the terminal and I don't get any response, it just skips over. What do you think could be the problem?

Comment: Sounds like the VM settings for the network are set to NAT and not Bridged.

Comment: Is it the same issue on VirtualBox as well?

Comment: Yes.  By default when you setup VMs the network settings default to NAT and not Bridged so that they are in their own little network.  If you set to Bridged then it opens up the VM to the full network.

Comment: On one of my system, my VM is set to NAT, but i get an output for the ```ip neigh``` command, but on another system the same command doesn't give me an output. Any idea how that happens?

Comment: In your second one that is not showing any output, is it set to DHCP and did it receive an IP address from the VM itself?

Comment: It received an IP address from the VM itself

Comment: Does the command `ip` by itself produce any output like the usage screen?

Comment: Yeah, i get the usage screen

Comment: I would suggest then filing a bug report on that specific one since it should be working.  `ubuntu-bug ip`